# Accepting multiple arguments in a Handlebars helper

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I've checked across message boards but have not found an answer to this.

My goal is to create a handlebars helper that will check if all arguments passed are true, and if so, display the content.

For example:

```
{{#ifAll data.something data.somethingElse data.oneMore}}
   Show me if all of these arguments exist!
{{/ifAll}}
```

This is my best stab - but is it dangerous that I'm assuming the last property will be the options property? Is there a better way to do this?

```
Handlebars.registerHelper "ifAll", ->
    options = arguments[arguments.length - 1]
    for arg, i in arguments when i isnt arguments.length - 1
        return options.inverse @ if !arg
    options.fn @
```

Comment: Shouldn't your helper be called rather `ifAll` not `ifAny` since you wan't it to show the contents if all arguments exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK `options` will always be the last argument. Helpers aren't exactly documented or specified that well but I think it is pretty safe to assume that the last argument is always going to be `options`.

That said, you can do this a little cleaner in CoffeeScript using a splat argument:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper "ifAny", (conditions..., options)->
    for condition in conditions
        return options.inverse @ if !condition
    options.fn @
```

or perhaps:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper "ifAny", (conditions..., options)->
    for condition in conditions
        return options.inverse @ unless condition
    options.fn @
```

or maybe even:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper "ifAny", (conditions..., options)->
    return options.inverse @ for condition in conditions when !condition
    options.fn @
```

---

[Kamil Szot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166921/kamil-szot) has pointed out that your helper name (`ifAny`) doesn't match the logic you're using. Your logic for `ifAny` really should be in a helper called `ifAll` and `ifAny` should be one of these:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper 'ifAny', (conditions..., options)->
    for condition in conditions
        return options.fn @ if condition
    options.inverse @

Handlebars.registerHelper 'ifAny', (conditions..., options)->
    return options.fn @ for condition in conditions when condition
    options.inverse @
```

Comment: Isn't this rather the logic for `ifAll`, not `ifAny` ?

Comment: @KamilSzot: Yes, I think you're right. I didn't even notice the helper name.

Comment: @Ben The updated answer has everything covered, right?